# How to scale an overlay on a video

Tags: ffmpeg

**What I am trying to do:**

How can I add an overlay image to a video that scales from frame A to frame B within time T.

**What I have achieved:**

I am able to add overlay like this:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=$X:$Y:enable='between(t,$START_TIME,$STOP_TIME)'"
```

**Where I am stuck:**

How can I add scaling here in this filter?

[A reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y70TH.png)